# How to match and extract text from dataframe in pandas using fuzzy logic?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame as follows:
DF1:

```
Name                     Value
buying fish hook         240
arrange lunch            75
repair equipment         800
purchase air condition   1400
buying fish              66
```

DF 2:

```
Name
fish
lunch
equipemt
air condition
hair condition
fish hook
```

I want to match the name in name columns from both dataframe with fuzzy logic and add name column from second dataframe to first as:

```
Name                     Value    item
buying fish hook         240      fish hook
arrange lunch            75       lunch
repair equipment         800      equipment
purchase air condition   1400     air condition
```

not all names have exact match. Df 2 has several names and some have matching words ex: air condition and hair condition. Splitting values from DF 1 causes miss match where fish hook is matched only with fish

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `next` and a generator expression. This method will give priority, in the case of multiple matches, by row order in `df2`. If no match is found, `find_key` will return `None`.

```
def find_key(x):
    return next((i for i in df2['Name'].values if x in i), None)

df1['item'] = df1['Name'].apply(find_key)
```

Comment: I have updated the example in question. There are several names which have same words and since there are multiple word in df1 i cannot use exact match. I tried splitting the sentence but as shown in the example air condition matches with hair condition, name fish hook matches with fish. Hence calculating distance using fuzzy logic would be more helpful.

Comment: @someone, OK, this changes your question massively. This is a non-trivial problem. Now you are trying to find the longest possible string match. I'll leave answer as a community wiki for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
i = 0
scorethreshold = 70
df1["fuzzy"] = 0
for x in df1.Name:
    noun,score,record = process.extractOne(x,df2.Name)
    if score > scorethreshold:     
        df1.loc[i,'fuzzy'] = noun
    else:
        df1.loc[i,'fuzzy'] = None
    i = i + 1
```

This code will compare and match the text. Returns df2 value or None as per scorethreshold. You can modify threshold as per accuracy of the df2. You might also want to do some text processing to get better result.